# How to convert ArrayList<String[]> to multidimensional array String[][]?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, collections, classcastexception

I have a collection of String[] values, for example:

```
ArrayList<String[]> values = new ArrayList<>();

String[] data1 = new String[]{"asd", "asdds", "ds"};
String[] data2 = new String[]{"dss", "21ss", "pp"};

values.add(data1);
values.add(data2);
```

And I need convert this to multidimensional array String[][].
When I try this:

```
String[][] arr = (String[][])values.toArray();
```

I get a `ClassCastException`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this (this does **not** require Java 11 while `toArray(String[][]::new)` requires)

```java
values.toArray(new String[0][0]);
```

That method is:

```java
/**
 * Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
 * sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned
 * array is that of the specified array.  If the list fits in the
 * specified array, it is returned therein.  Otherwise, a new array is
 * allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of
 * this list.
```

Answer (score 4):

No don't need to cast, check [**the doc**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-), you can just use:

```
String[][] arr = values.toArray(new String[0][]);
```

Or if you are using [**Java 11**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction))

```
String[][] arr = values.toArray(String[][]::new);
```